# On jQuery.post, I get the message: The method GET is not allowed for the requested URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I have the following problem:

I work on a Flask application, and I want to pass some data to the server via AJAX. I am pretty new on this AJAX thing, so I can't get something right.

On my client side, when the user clicks on an icon, I want to pass some data via *jQuery.post* stored in the variable *message:*

```
jQuery("#icon_ID").click(function() {
    var message = {
        'GRAPH_TYPE': graphType
    };
    var _sendOnSuccess = function () {
    }

    var jqxhr = jQuery.post('/graph', message, _sendOnSuccess, 'json');
});
```

On my server side, I have the following code:

```
@app.route('/graph', methods = ['POST'])
@login_required
def physical_graph():
    ret_data = request.form['GRAPH_TYPE']
    return ""
```

All I want to do for now is to access the GRAPH_TYPE on the server side. However, when I click on the icon, I get the error message:

> Method Not Allowed
>
> The method GET is not allowed for the requested URL.

I really don't understand why Python tells me that I am using the GET method, when in fact I am using the POST method.

Can please someone help me with this? What should I do to solve this problem? If there's some other method I can use, feel free to give me advice of any kind. Just bear in mind that  besides jQuery, I don't want to use other JavaScript library.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did you confirm an actual POST was being made?

Comment: I would use the firebug console on firefox or the network XHR on chrome to check the details of the ajax call.

Comment: On console. when I click on the 'icon_ID' icon, I get: GET /graph HTTP/1.1" 405, which means that a GET was made instead of POST, but I don't know why. I hope that was what you were asking?

Comment: I work on Chrome btw, if that's important.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are passing an `object` as `data` like

```
var message = {
    'GRAPH_TYPE': graphType
};
```

In this case `jQuery` attempts to URL encode the object and by default sends with the data type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` ans sends a `GET` request. To overcome this problem make sure that you’re passing `jQuery` a string for the data parameter and to do this you can use `JSON.stringify` like

```
var message = JSON.stringify({ "GRAPH_TYPE": graphType });
```

Comment: But [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) accepts [PlainObjects](http://api.jquery.com/Types#PlainObject), so the `message` should be fine.

Comment: @Sheikh Heera: when I try your way - it's the same, so probably that's not the problem. Any other ideas?